# Waiting for bytes to be ready

Tags: c#, multithreading

What this should do is wait for `dataBlockSize` bytes to be ready and then continue, but wait for 10ms if they are not ready yet to not block the CPU, but not the first time as I do not want to wait once even if the bytes are ready.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{                   
    var ftdiStatus = ftdiDevice.GetRxBytesWaiting(ref rxBytes);
    if (ftdiStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
        return null;

    if (rxBytes >= dataBlockSize)
        break;

    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is just a matter of taste. Here is one approach:

```
do
{
    var ftdiStatus = FtdiDevice.FtdiDevice.Instance.GetRxBytesWaiting(ref rxBytes);

    if (ftdiStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
        return null;

    if(rxBytes >= dataBlockSize)
        break;

    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
while (true); // Perhaps a check for timeout?
```

Comment: This method is very similar to what I use when I get data back from my ftdi devices. I think it looks good and is easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to use `ManualResetEvent`. This way your thread will wake up on cancellation instead of sleeping for 10 ms.

```
do
{                   
    var ftdiStatus = ftdiDevice.GetRxBytesWaiting(ref rxBytes);
    if (ftdiStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
        return null;

    if (rxBytes >= dataBlockSize)
        break;
}
while (!cancelEvent.WaitOne(10));
```